# Creating a dashboard portal which will give a good interactive OLAP view to the user

Tags: pentaho, saiku, pentaho-ctools

I have a requirement as to create cubesbased on some fact and dimension tables and then publishing it in localhost.There will be a portal where user can login and can see the charts and can do slice and dice and can add filters and able to see the reports.

I have downloaded Pentaho BI server CE 5.2.0 version for publishing

and

Pentaho Schema Workbench 3.9.0 for creating cubes.

I was working in JPivot and created some sample cubes and published successfully in localhost.But it is not giving that drag and drop features.

I wanted to know how to install SAIKU Analytics(as i believe drag and drop features are present there) in Windows system for Community version and also how to create the dashboard/Portal(by which Ctool) consisting of multiple charts where user can select filter and based on it the charts will populate.

Also the dashboard can give a good UI experience to the user

I am an ETL developer and am new to this Pentaho OLAP designing.Please help me on this

Answer (score 0):

For Saiku, you can install it with the marketplace from Pentaho menu.
It will download the plugin and install it under the directory 
biserver-ce/pentaho-solutions/system/saiku
Then, you will have to restart your server.

For the Ctools, you can find tutorials on the web and look for the documentation ; see for example http://www.webdetails.pt/ and the community forum :
http://forums.pentaho.com/